# Creating an affinity-matrix between protein and RNA sequences

Tags: python, performance, array, numpy, hash-map

I wrote an algorithm that analyzes protein-RNA interactions and I found that the following function is the bottleneck that causes performance issues:

```
import numpy as np
#len(protein_sequence)~500, len(rna_sequence)~1500

def affinity_matrix(protein_sequence, rna_sequence): 
    python_matrix = [[] for _ in range(len(protein_sequence))]

    for i, AA in enumerate(protein_sequence):
        for base in rna_sequence:
            python_matrix[i].append(scales[base][AA])
            #(Where "scales" is a small dict() with the structure: 
            #scales[base][AA] = float(), with 4 bases and 20 AA, so 80 values total.)
    return(np.array(python_matrix))
```

I suspect 2 problems in this code, but I don't know how to solve them:

1. I am retrieving values from this `scales` `dict` millions of times, and it's said calling values from "non-static" data structures like `dict()` is slow. So how can I make this small dictionary "static" instead? (This dictionary is only created once, while the `rna_sequence` and `protein_sequence` will be different each time I call the function.)
2. I am building the matrix at first with pythons tools, and later I convert it into the (faster) NumPy array. Possibly it is faster to directly create it with NumPy, but I am not sure if this is possible.

I am thankful for any tips how to improve this code or references to guides that would help in this case.

Here is example data, in case you want to try out the algorithm:

```
rna_sequence = 'ACAGGAGGAGCCGCUCGCUGGCGGCUGAUCCAGCGUCUCCGUGACAGGCACCCUGCUCCGCCGCCACCGCCACCGCCACCGCCACCGUCGCCUUUUCUUCUUCGUCCCGGGCGGUGCGUUCCACUGCUCUGGGGCCGGCGCCGCGCCCAGUCCCGCUUCGGGCCGCAAGCCCCACCGCUCCCCUCCCCGGGCAGGGGCGCCGCGCAGCCCGCUCCCGCCGCCACCUCCUCCCCUGCCGCCCUCCUAGCCGGCAGGAAUUGCGCGACCACAGCGCCGCUCGCGUCGCCCGCAUCAGCUCAGCCCGCUGCCGCUCGGCCCUCGGCACCGCUCCGGGUCCGGCCGCCGCGCGGCCAGGGCUCCCCCUGCCCAGCGCUCCCAGGCCCCGCCACGCGUCGCCGCGCCCAGCUCCAGUCUCCCCUCCCCGGGGUCUCGCCAGCCCCUUCCUGCAGCCGCCGCCUCCGAAGGAGCGGGUCCGCCGCGGGUAACCAUGCCUAGCAAAACCAAGUACAACCUUGUGGACGAUGGGCACGACCUGCGGAUCCCCUUGCACAACGAGGACGCCUUCCAGCACGGCAUCUGCUUUGAGGCCAAGUACGUAGGAAGCCUGGACGUGCCAAGGCCCAACAGCAGGGUGGAGAUCGUGGCUGCCAUGCGCCGGAUACGGUAUGAGUUUAAAGCCAAGAACAUCAAGAAGAAGAAAGUGAGCAUUAUGGUUUCAGUGGAUGGAGUGAAAGUGAUUCUGAAGAAGAAGAAAAAGCUUCUUUUAUUGCAGAAAAAGGAAUGGACGUGGGAUGAGAGCAAGAUGCUGGUGAUGCAGGACCCCAUCUACAGGAUCUUCUAUGUCUCUCAUGAUUCCCAAGACUUGAAGAUCUUCAGCUAUAUCGCUCGAGAUGGUGCCAGCAAUAUCUUCAGGUGUAACGUCUUUAAAUCCAAGAAGAAGAGCCAAGCUAUGAGAAUCGUUCGGACGGUGGGGCAGGCCUUUGAGGUCUGCCACAAGCUGAGCCUGCAGCACACGCAGCAGAAUGCAGAUGGCCAGGAAGAUGGAGAGAGCGAGAGGAACAGCAACAGCUCAGGAGACCCAGGCCGCCAGCUCACUGGAGCCGAGAGGGCCUCCACGGCCACUGCAGAGGAGACUGACAUCGAUGCGGUGGAGGUCCCACUUCCAGGGAAUGAUGUCCUGGAAUUCAGCCGAGGUGUGACUGAUCUAGAUGCUGUAGGGAAGGAAGGAGGCUCUCACACAGGCUCCAAGGUUUCGCACCCCCAGGAGCCCAUGCUGACAGCCUCACCCAGGAUGCUGCUCCCUUCUUCUUCCUCGAAGCCUCCAGGCCUGGGCACAGAGACACCGCUGUCCACUCACCACCAGAUGCAGCUCCUCCAGCAGCUCCUCCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGACACAAGUGGCUGUGGCCCAGGUACACUUGCUGAAGGACCAGUUGGCUGCUGAGGCUGCGGCGCGGCUGGAGGCCCAGGCUCGCGUGCAUCAGCUUUUGCUGCAGAACAAGGACAUGCUCCAGCACAUCUCCCUGCUGGUCAAGCAGGUGCAAGAGCUGGAACUGAAGCUGUCAGGACAGAACGCCAUGGGCUCCCAGGACAGCUUGCUGGAGAUCACCUUCCGCUCCGGAGCCCUGCCCGUGCUCUGUGACCCCACGACCCCUAAGCCAGAGGACCUGCAUUCGCCGCCGCUGGGCGCGGGCUUGGCUGACUUUGCCCACCCUGCGGGCAGCCCCUUAGGUAGGCGCGACUGCUUGGUGAAGCUGGAGUGCUUUCGCUUUCUUCCGCCCGAGGACACCCCGCCCCCAGCGCAGGGCGAGGCGCUCCUGGGCGGUCUGGAGCUCAUCAAGUUCCGAGAGUCAGGCAUCGCCUCGGAGUACGAGUCCAACACGGACGAGAGCGAGGAGCGCGACUCGUGGUCCCAGGAGGAGCUGCCGCGCCUGCUGAAUGUCCUGCAGAGGCAGGAACUGGGCGACGGCCUGGAUGAUGAGAUCGCCGUGUAGGUGCCGAGGGCGAGGAGAUGGAGGCGGCGGCGUGGCUGGAGGGGCCGUGUCUGGCUGCUGCCCGGGUAGGGGAUGCCCAGUGAAUGUGCACUGCCGAGGAGAAUGCCAGCCAGGGCCCGGGAGAGUGUGAGGUUUCAGGAAAGUAUUGAGAUUCUGCUUUGGAGGGUAAAGUGGGGAAGAAAUCGGAUUCCCAGAGGUGAAUCAGCUCCUCUCCUACUUGUGACUAGAGGGUGGUGGAGGUAAGGCCUUCCAGAGCCCAUGGCUUCAGGAGAGGGUCUCUCUCCAGGACUGCCAGGCUGCUGGAGGACCUGCCCCUACCUGCUGCAUCGUCAGGCUCCCACGCUUUGUCCGUGAUGCCCCCCUACCCCCUCACUCUCCCCGUCUCCAUGGUCCCGACCAGGAAGGGAAGCCAUCGGUACCUUCUCAGGUACUUUGUUUCUGGAUAUCACGAUGCUGCGAGUUGCCUAACCCUCCCCCUACCUUUAUGAGAGGAAUUCCUUCUCCAGGCCCUUGCUGAGAUUGUAGAGAUUGAGUGCUCUGGACCGCAAAAGCCAGGCUAGUCCUUGUAGGGUGAGCAUGGAAUUGGAAUGUGUCACAGUGGAUAAGCUUUUAGAGGAACUGAAUCCAAACAUUUUCUCCAGCCGGACAUUGAAUGUUGCUACAAAGGGAGCCUUGAAGCUUUAACAUGGUUCAGGCCCUUGGUGUGAGAGCCCAGGGGGAGGACAGCUUGUCUGCUGCUCCAAAUCACUUAGAUCUGAUUCCUGUUUUGAAAGUCCUGCCCUGCCUUCCUCCUGCCUGUAGCCCAGCCCAUCUAAAUGGAAGCUGGGAAUUGCCCCUCACCUCCCCUGUGUCCUGUCCAGCUGAAGCUUUUGCAGCACUUUACCUCUCUGAAAGCCCCAGAGGACCAGAGCCCCCAGCCUUACCUCUCAACCUGUCCCCUCCACUGGGCAGUGGUGGUCAGUUUUUACUGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAGAGAAAGAAAAAAAAGAAUGAAUGCAAGCUGAUAGCUGAGACUGUGAGACUGUUUUUGUCCACUCUUCUGAAUCACUGCCACUUGGGUCAGGGACCACAGCCAUUGCCACCCUUGGCCCAUCUCUCUGCGUGCGUGCCUUGAGCACACAUAUAAAAAGUGCCAUGUGCAAUUGUCUUAUCUUUUAUGAUCUAGGCUUUGCCUAGGGAUCACUACUCCUUAACGGGCUGGCUGGGGCAAUGAGGAAAAGCUCCUUUGCUCCUGUAAGGCCAUAAGUGGCUGUUAACAGAUUUUCAAAUGCCUGAAGAGAUUGCUGAGACCUGCUAGAGUCAUAUGUUCGGGGAAUUAAGUCUUUAUCCUAGACAACAAGGUACAGAUGCAAACUGCAGUGUUAUUGGAGGGUCAAUCGGCAAGGAUAUGAUUAUCCCAAAAUGGAGUUCAUCGACCCUAGCUUUCCUUUAGAUUAUAUAUAAAUAAAAGUGCAGUCCUCUUCUAAUGGCCACAGUUGGUUUUCUUGUAGCCCAGAAAGUCCAAAUUAAAGGAAAUAAAUUCAGUUUUAUGUUAGCCUUCCUUGGUGCAUCAGGGUGUCAGUGGAAAUAGGAUCAGGUGGUGUGUGUGUGUGUGUUUUGUGUGUGUGUGUACACAUGUGUUUAUAUAUACAUGUGUGAGGGAAAGUGUGUACAUAUAUGUAGGAUUGUAACCAGACGGAAAAGAACGAGGAUCUCCAGGGUGUUUGAAUCAGCAACAGAUUUGUGUUUUCUAACAUGCAUUUAGUUGGAGAGGCAUGGUUCUGUUUGUUUUGUUUUGAUCUAAUUUGCCAUUGGAAAUAGGUACAGUUACACAGAGAAGGAAGAACCAGGAAAGUGAGAUCCAUGAAACUAAAUGAGCAGCUGUCAGAAUCCAGUGUGGCUGAGCCUACCUAGCUUAUGAAAUCUAACCCAGGGUUCCCUGAGUCCAAGACCACUUAGAUUAUUAAGAUUUUGAACGUCCAGAGGAGUGAAAAGUCUGUUUUCUGACGUAAGCCGGAGCUGAGGAUAAAGCCAGAGGCCAGUGGAUUAGGUGUAUGGAAUGUGGAUGGAGAGGGCUUGUGUGGGAUGUGGCCAGGGAGUGGGUGAGGAAGGCCGCUUCUAAAUGGCCUGUAAAAACUUGAGAUUGGAUAGACGAAAGGAAAUGGAGAAAUUAAAGAAUUGGAGAAACUAGUUAUCUGUGUUGCUGACUUUGGGACCCAUCCAAGACUCCUGCCCUUGGGGUGUUCCAUGGUGGUUUCUUCCUGCCUGGGCGCCACCCUUUCCCCAGUUCAGGCCCUCCCUGGAGGACUAGUUUGUGUAUUGGUAUCCUCCCCAGUGGACCCAAACCAGCGCAUACUUGGUGUGUGGAGAUGGGAGACAAAGGACAGAUCUAGGAGCCUUGAAGGAUCACCAGCCACCGACCCUCCAUCAGGGCCAACUGGGCAGGAAAGGGAACAUUGCAGACCUGAUUUCCCGACGAUGUCACCCUGUCCUCCCUCCUUGCUUCUUGCUCUGCUAACUCAACUCUGCCUUCCUCUUUUUCAUUCUUCUACUCUGCCCUAUAUGGAGGACAAAUGGACACCAGGGGUGCUAACCUUAUUGGUGCCUGCCCCAGCCUACCCCAGGUGCCAGCAGACUCUCGUGCACAGGAGGCUCCCACAGUUAUGGAGCCAGGAAAGAAUUUCUCUGCACUGGAUGGACUGUAUAUUGAGAUUAAAAAUUAUAUUCCUUAUAUUCCUGCUUAUAUCAAUGCUCUCUCUGUAAAACCUCUUCCUAGCCUCAUUUCUCUCAACUGAUCUUGUUUAGGCGUUGUAUUCCUUUUAUUUACUCUUUGCUUGACUGCUUCCUCCUAACCCUCUACCCACUAGCACUCUACUUCCUAAAGCUGUUGUGUCAUUAACUCUGUUGGAUCAACUCUCUGGGAAAAGAUUCUGUUAAUGUAAGUGCACUUACUCCCUGGAUGUUGUCACUAGUCUAGUGGCUUUUGCUAAAUAAACCUUUCUUAUUUCUA'
protein_sequence = 'MPSKTKYNLVDDGHDLRIPLHNEDAFQHGICFEAKYVGSLDVPRPNSRVEIVAAMRRIRYEFKAKNIKKKKVSIMVSVDGVKVILKKKKKLLLLQKKEWTWDESKMLVMQDPIYRIFYVSHDSQDLKIFSYIARDGASNIFRCNVFKSKKKSQAMRIVRTVGQAFEVCHKLSLQHTQQNADGQEDGESERNSNSSGDPGRQLTGAERASTATAEETDIDAVEVPLPGNDVLEFSRGVTDLDAVGKEGGSHTGSKVSHPQEPMLTASPRMLLPSSSSKPPGLGTETPLSTHHQMQLLQQLLQQQQQQTQVAVAQVHLLKDQLAAEAAARLEAQARVHQLLLQNKDMLQHISLLVKQVQELELKLSGQNAMGSQDSLLEITFRSGALPVLCDPTTPKPEDLHSPPLGAGLADFAHPAGSPLGRRDCLVKLECFRFLPPEDTPPPAQGEALLGGLELIKFRESGIASEYESNTDESEERDSWSQEELPRLLNVLQRQELGDGLDDEIAV'
scales = {'A': {'A': -0.103534,
  'C': -0.141027,
  'D': -0.057364,
  'E': 0.025673,
  'F': -0.160025,
  'G': 0.155926,
  'H': 0.114486,
  'I': -0.064125,
  'K': 0.058532,
  'L': -0.093059,
  'M': -0.093239,
  'N': 0.211717,
  'P': -0.187549,
  'Q': 0.286417,
  'R': 0.045458,
  'S': -0.068299,
  'T': -0.256675,
  'V': -0.126037,
  'W': -0.352338,
  'Y': -0.059715},
 'C': {'A': -0.170978,
  'C': 0.460587,
  'D': 0.011352,
  'E': 0.456847,
  'F': -0.157944,
  'G': 0.209027,
  'H': -0.166851,
  'I': -0.016438,
  'K': 0.093534,
  'L': 0.112175,
  'M': -0.08656,
  'N': 0.439522,
  'P': -0.189412,
  'Q': -0.031332,
  'R': 0.009869,
  'S': -0.357084,
  'T': -0.360561,
  'V': 0.248514,
  'W': 0.417484,
  'Y': 0.059507},
 'G': {'A': 0.157098,
  'C': 0.006956,
  'D': 0.047448,
  'E': -0.193184,
  'F': 0.480436,
  'G': -0.279106,
  'H': 0.144117,
  'I': 0.170305,
  'K': -0.186721,
  'L': 0.177462,
  'M': -0.139056,
  'N': -0.225754,
  'P': 0.097558,
  'Q': -0.085275,
  'R': -0.055897,
  'S': 0.273463,
  'T': 0.166763,
  'V': 0.108108,
  'W': 0.093968,
  'Y': 0.263202},
 'U': {'A': 0.130008,
  'C': -0.012462,
  'D': 0.005557,
  'E': 0.043517,
  'F': -0.269202,
  'G': -0.031819,
  'H': -0.198936,
  'I': -0.084679,
  'K': 0.096389,
  'L': -0.153234,
  'M': 0.351179,
  'N': -0.215165,
  'P': 0.240871,
  'Q': -0.065384,
  'R': 0.005856,
  'S': 0.31803,
  'T': 0.264754,
  'V': -0.078486,
  'W': 0.094917,
  'Y': -0.118544}}
```

Comment: "*I am loading this dictionary millions of times*"  and "*So how can I make this small dictionary "static" instead?*" - are you declaring that dict within a `for` loop?

Comment: No, the dict is only created once. (I don't really know what "static" fully means..)

Comment: Ok, then, what does mean your "I am loading this dictionary millions of times"?

Comment: Sorry for my inaccurate language! I mean I retrieve values from it many times. In this function 500*1500 times and I call this function many thousand times.

Comment: So the RNA and protein sequences always will be different, but the "scales" dictionary is always the same one.

Comment: Is that number `1.1111` intended always be the same for all `rna` keys?

Comment: In reality it's always a different number with a similar number of decimals. I just didn't want to copy-paste a whole dictionary for reasons of staying compact. Should I provide the real numbers?

Comment: Yes, for this case it's better to post the actual scales with real numbers if they differ

Comment: I see. I just did.

Comment: And the last question please, how do "performance issues" appear? time perfromance, memory? What's your current perf. statistics on your environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is likely not the dictionary look-up that kills your performance here, and more those nested `for` loops. [Python is known for its notoriously slow (`for`) loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw).

Since my numpy fu is a little bit weak lately, short of writing the code in C(++), I could only come up with an improvement using a nested list comprehension:

```
def affinity_matrix_lc(protein_sequence, rna_sequence):
    python_matrix = [[scales[base][item] for base in rna_sequence]
                     for item in protein_sequence]

    return np.array(python_matrix)
```

Conceptually it is very similar to [RomanPerekhrest's version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/233072/92478), but slightly easier to see what's going on I would say.

The list comprehension reduces the runtime of your example by about 30% here on my machine, with on-par performance to the one from Roman.

```
%timeit affinity_matrix_op(protein_sequence, rna_sequence)   # your original code
409 ms ± 3.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit affinity_matrix_rp(protein_sequence, rna_sequence)   # RomanPerekhrest's version
277 ms ± 5.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit affinity_matrix_lc(protein_sequence, rna_sequence)              
275 ms ± 2.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Edit - int version at OP's request:

I cobbled up a version of your code that first performs a translation to a vector of `int`s for both inputs. The look-up then uses numpy's indexing and broadcasting features to get the affinity matrix:

```
RNA_MAPPING = {'U': 0, 'G': 1, 'C': 2, 'A': 3}
PROTEIN_MAPPING = {
    'R': 0,'A': 1,'S': 2,'D': 3,'Q': 4,'N': 5,'W': 6,'V': 7,'L': 8,'K': 9,
    'H': 10,'E': 11,'C': 12,'G': 13,'Y': 14,'P': 15,'M': 16,'I': 17,'T': 18,
    'F': 19
}
LUT = np.array([
    [ 0.005856,  0.130008,  0.31803 ,  0.005557, -0.065384, -0.215165,
      0.094917, -0.078486, -0.153234,  0.096389, -0.198936,  0.043517,
     -0.012462, -0.031819, -0.118544,  0.240871,  0.351179, -0.084679,
      0.264754, -0.269202],
    [-0.055897,  0.157098,  0.273463,  0.047448, -0.085275, -0.225754,
      0.093968,  0.108108,  0.177462, -0.186721,  0.144117, -0.193184,
      0.006956, -0.279106,  0.263202,  0.097558, -0.139056,  0.170305,
      0.166763,  0.480436],
    [ 0.009869, -0.170978, -0.357084,  0.011352, -0.031332,  0.439522,
      0.417484,  0.248514,  0.112175,  0.093534, -0.166851,  0.456847,
      0.460587,  0.209027,  0.059507, -0.189412, -0.08656 , -0.016438,
     -0.360561, -0.157944],
    [ 0.045458, -0.103534, -0.068299, -0.057364,  0.286417,  0.211717,
     -0.352338, -0.126037, -0.093059,  0.058532,  0.114486,  0.025673,
     -0.141027,  0.155926, -0.059715, -0.187549, -0.093239, -0.064125,
     -0.256675, -0.160025]
])

def affinity_matrix_int(protein_sequence, rna_sequence):
    protein_sequence_int = np.array(
        [PROTEIN_MAPPING[i] for i in protein_sequence], dtype=int
    ).reshape(-1, 1)
    rna_sequence_int = np.array(
        [RNA_MAPPING[i] for i in rna_sequence], dtype=int
    ).reshape(1, -1)
    return LUT[rna_sequence_int, protein_sequence_int]
```

I then checked the correctness of the implementation using

```
>>> np.allclose(
        affinity_matrix_int(protein_sequence, rna_sequence),
        affinity_matrix_op(protein_sequence, rna_sequence)
    )
True
```

And did another round of timing:

```
%timeit affinity_matrix_int(protein_sequence, rna_sequence)             
10.9 ms ± 36.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

To answer your question in the comments: It turns out, this is quite a bit faster ;-)

Comment: Great, I didn't know one-liners are actually faster. This improved my programing in general, not just for this example! Thanks! And would it improve the performance if I converted the RNA and protein sequence data-sets to vektors of integers? Then maybe I could use a numpy 2d matrix instead of the scales-dict? Would that make it much faster?

Comment: Should the frequent AA be represented by low or high integers?

Comment: @KaPy3141 I did a test implementation and included it in the answer. In my test it was quite a bit faster. You will have to see yourself how this works out in your application.

Comment: Wow, that's just incredible! This is what I cal an improvement! :) And this when converting each RNA and protein within the function, which I could do beforehand. Just awesome!

Comment: What does dtype=int
    ).reshape(-1, 1), if I may ask?

Comment: Python lists are 1D by default, [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) transforms it into a 2D column vector (-1 rows (i.e. choose automatically) x 1 column). You could also specify the exact shape explicitly  as `.reshape(len(protein_sequence), 1)`.

Answer (score 8):

#### *Boosting performance*

The initial approach creates a 2-dimensional list of empty lists beforehand and performs 2 538 096 expensive `list.append` operations.

To make it go faster and more efficiently we'll go through 2 steps:

- schedule a generator/iterator yielding a sequence of all the needed values
- generate `numpy` array from the scheduled *generaor* with convenient [`numpy.fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) routine and immediately giving a new shape to the array with [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) routine (assuming that `len(protein_sequence)` points to number of *rows* and `len(rna_sequence)` is a number of *columns*)

---

The final optimized **`affinity_matrix`** function:

```
def affinity_matrix(protein_sequence, rna_sequence):
    it = (scales[base][prot] for prot in protein_sequence for base in rna_sequence)
    return np.fromiter(it, dtype=float).reshape(len(protein_sequence), len(rna_sequence))
```

---

Let's move to tests. I've renamed the old function to `affinity_matrix_old` for comparison.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('affinity_matrix_old(protein_sequence, rna_sequence)', setup='from __main__ import affinity_matrix_old, protein_sequence, rna_sequence', number=10)
3.1148553189996164
>>> timeit('affinity_matrix(protein_sequence, rna_sequence)', setup='from __main__ import affinity_matrix, protein_sequence, rna_sequence', number=10)
1.9052914250059985
```

---

The resulting array looks as:

```
>>> affinity_matrix(protein_sequence, rna_sequence)
array([[-0.093239, -0.08656 , -0.093239, ..., -0.08656 ,  0.351179,
        -0.093239],
       [-0.187549, -0.189412, -0.187549, ..., -0.189412,  0.240871,
        -0.187549],
       [-0.068299, -0.357084, -0.068299, ..., -0.357084,  0.31803 ,
        -0.068299],
       ...,
       [-0.064125, -0.016438, -0.064125, ..., -0.016438, -0.084679,
        -0.064125],
       [-0.103534, -0.170978, -0.103534, ..., -0.170978,  0.130008,
        -0.103534],
       [-0.126037,  0.248514, -0.126037, ...,  0.248514, -0.078486,
        -0.126037]])
```

Comment: Great, from now on I will try to avoid append() as much as possible! And the dict() is ok? I thought of something like converting all RNA and protein sequences to vectors of integers. Then maybe I can transform the scale-dict to a 2d Numpy array? Would that be much faster?

Comment: @KaPy3141, I would say for this case - your `scales` dict is good. Whatever structure it would be transformed to - that structure still will be indexed **2 538 096** times due to 2 input factors `protein_sequence/rna_sequence`. Let's say if I collapse your dict into 1-level structure like `scales_1d = {(base, k): num for base, rna_data in scales.items() for k, num in rna_data.items()}` (having compound keys) - that will run slower. As another way: if we transform the dict into a dataframe `scales_pd = pd.DataFrame(scales)` - that would be even more slower.

Answer (score 5):

You can speed this further in 2 ways.

## local variables

a local variable lookup is faster than  a global. Since you lookup scales an awful lot, this can improve performance

## np.fromiter

where you can even specify the initial length to improve performance further

```
def affinity_matrix_generator(protein_sequence, rna_sequence, scales=scales):
    for base in rna_sequence:
        base_scale = scales[base]  # saving another dict lookup
        for protein in protein_sequence:
            yield base_scale[protein]

def affinity_matrix(protein_sequence, rna_sequence, scales=scales):
    iterator = affinity_matrix_generator(protein_sequence, rna_sequence, scales=scales)
    size = len(protein_sequence) * len(rna_sequence)
    return np.fromiter(iterator, dtype=float, count=size).reshape(len(protein_sequence), len(rna_sequence))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! (+1) I will use this general knowledge from on! Unfortunately your suggestion was slower than the original code. But I was able to use your input in general to improve others suggestions. For example AlexVs original suggestion is improved by 10% if I save the full dict locally within the function!